# Using pandas to save descriptors into csv

Tags: python, opencv

I have problem with my code. I want to save HOG descriptors into csv file.

Code:

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd

def getHogFromImage(im):
   hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
   h = hog.compute(cv2.imread(im))
   return h

h1 = getHogFromImage("apple.jpg")
h2 = getHogFromImage("peach.jpg")

apple = pd.DataFrame("1," + h1) #any idea how do it?
peach = pd.DataFrame("0," + h2)

apple.to_csv('foo.csv', index=False, header=None, sep=",", line_terminator="\n")
peach.to_csv('foo.csv', index=False, header=None, sep=",", line_terminator="\n")
```

My foo.csv file

```
0.15200253
0.16865349
0.0909358
0.13702433
0.15322956
0.14372425
0.18107016
0.12029551
0.065096505
0.20796815
0.28659236
0.15984383
0.12754892
0.15886153
.
.
.
```

But I need save the descriptors into file in this format

```
1, 0.15200253, 0.16865349, 0.0909358, 0.13702433 .....
0, 0.16865349, 0.0909358, 0.13702433
```

So all descriptor data will be in one line separated by ",". But when image will be apple the first value will be "1" and when image will be peach the first value will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your hog values are lists of floats, you can just make a list of lists inside the dataframe constructor by putting your h values inside []'s

```
df = pd.DataFrame([h1,h2]).to_csv('foo.csv', index=False, header=None, sep=",", line_terminator="\n")
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris but problem is now with ValueError 
I try this: 
`h1 = getHogFromImage(paths[0])
h2 = getHogFromImage(paths[0])
pd.DataFrame([h1,h2]).to_csv('foo.csv', index=False, header=None, sep=",", line_terminator="\n")`

Comment: change [h1, h2] to [h1.flatten(), h2.flatten()]

Comment: I have still only one line in foo.csv